# "With his right arm raised"

Tags: past-participles

> With his right arm raised, I was thinking ...

I thought with his right arm raising. Why use raised?

Comment: _Raise_ is a transitive verb (it must have an object). We say _He was raising his arm_ or _His arm was raised_ (the past participle acting as an adjective describing the position of the arm).

Comment: Even if you could use raising, the order of the partial sentence indicates that his arm was already up before the speaker did whatever followed.

Comment: Your text fragment ***is not valid English***. The participial element before the comma ***must be followed by the actual "subject"***. In this case, the subject of that initial clause is ***he*** (not ***I***). You'd have to have EITHER *With **his** right arm raised, **he** [did something]* OR *With **my** right arm raised, **I** [did something]*.